# When the ExtJS docs say a feature "requires core.css" what does this mean?

Tags: extjs

When the ExtJS docs say a feature "requires core.css" what does this mean?

I can't find a `core.css` anywhere in the ExtJS distribution.

Searching around Google points me to another library called GXT. Is this where I should get `core.css` from?

Answer (score 0):

Ext uses a preprocessor to compile the .css file from multiple source files.  The "core" css rules they are referring to are copied in from `path_to_extjs/resources/themes/stylesheets/ext4/default/core/_core.scss`

More info is [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/theming) in the documentation.

Comment: So I need to install compass and compile some CSS in order to get some styles? This can't be right... Isn't there an easier way, given that I'm not interested in customising anything right now and am happy with the defaults?

Comment: No, the core rules are included in all the ready built css files